# Mixed-Mode x-compile and microload markup is currently unsupported (EXTJS 4.1.1, sencha cmd 4.0)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am currently using EXTJS 4.1.1(GPL) and sencha cmd 4.0. I am trying to build my application into production as described in guides. Unfortunately I have got an error saying 'Mixed-Mode x-compile and microload markup is currently unsupported'.

Any help how to build into production using extjs 4.1.1 is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look at that post: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273418-Mixed-Mode-x-compile-and-microload-markup-is-currently-unsupported/page1

Comment: I did look at it, that was not what I was looking for...

Comment: what does your app.json file look like?

Comment: We generated the app structure ourselves - a custom app structure, there is no app.json file, we directly included extjs bootstrap into index file.

Answer (score 2):

Having single quotes in file references in the index.html file causes this problem. Change this:

```
<!-- <x-compile> -->
    <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.css'>
        <script src='ext/ext-all.js'></script>
        <script src='bootstrap.js'></script>
    <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
    <script src='app.js'></script>
<!-- </x-compile> -->
```

to

```
<!-- <x-compile> -->
    <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
        <script src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- </x-compile> -->
```

This fixed the problem for me.